# How to access database from nestjs guard

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Currently I try to learn nestjs, for that I followed the official (cat-)tutorial to build a basic user authentication system.

When you access the API to change the username or password, the request should check if the user is a valid user (reading user from database).
To store the user I already have a mongodb connection.

I´m currently struggeling how I can get the database module/access in the guard.

The guard is working but only returns true, I tried to Inject my database module but without success.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return this.validateRequest(request);
  }

  validateRequest(execContext: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>{
    const request = execContext.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Is it the right approach to extend the UserService class with a findOne method and inject it into the service?

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService{

    constructor(@Inject('USER_MODEL') private readonly userModel: Model<User>){}

    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User>{
        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
        return await createdUser.save();
    }

    async update(updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto): Promise<User>{
        const updateUser = new this.userModel(updateUserDto);
        return await this.userModel.updateOne({loginname: updateUser.loginname}, this.getUpdateQueryFromUserModel(updateUser));
    }

    async delete(deleteUserDto: DeleteUserDto): Promise<User>{
        const deleteUser = new this.userModel(deleteUserDto);
        return await this.userModel.deleteAll({loginname:deleteUser.loginname}).exec();
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
        return await this.userModel.find().exec();
    }

    getUpdateQueryFromUserModel(userModel: Model<User>): Object {
        let query = {};
        if(userModel.dispname !== undefined && userModel.dispname !== null){
            query["dispname"] = userModel.dispname;
        }
        if(userModel.pw !== undefined && userModel.pw !== null){
            query["pw"] = hash.sha256().update(userModel.pw).digest('hex');
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me what the right approch look like?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the database access, you can inject it directly (tried that before but failed cause of another problem).

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(@Inject('UserService')private readonly userService:UserService){}
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return this.validateRequest(request);
  }

  async validateRequest(execContext: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean>{
    const request = execContext.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    console.log(await this.userService.findAll());
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        return true;
    });
  }
}
```

My code is now looking like this with the service injected in the constructor, but it´s still not fully working, cause when I try to run the `execContext.switchToHttp().getRequest()` line, I get an error **switchToHttp is not a function**, can anyone help?

Greetings Pascal

Comment: You've already switched to the Http context of the request, in your `validateRequest` function you should accept a `Request` object instead of `ExecutionContext` OR you should not switch to the http context in the `canActivate` function.

Comment: When I did this, I got some errors for UserService and UserModule imports. How does your app.module.ts look like?

Comment: you should manage your modules so that the repository be accessible by the guard.

Answer (score 0):

this is my implementation and it works fine

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core'
import { IS_PUBLIC_KEY } from 'src/decorators'
import { IResourcePermission, RESOURCE_PERMISSION_KEY } from 'src/decorators/resource-permission.decorator'
import { RolesPermissionsLogicService } from 'src/modules/roles-permissions/services/roles-permissions-logic.service'

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizeGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly rolesPermissionsLogicService: RolesPermissionsLogicService,
    private reflector: Reflector,
  ) {}
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.validateRequest(context)
  }

  async validateRequest(ctx: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const isRoutePublic = this.reflector.get<string>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, ctx.getHandler())
    const resourcePermission = this.reflector.get<IResourcePermission>(RESOURCE_PERMISSION_KEY, ctx.getHandler())

    if (isRoutePublic || !resourcePermission) {
      return true
    }
    const { user } = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()

    const rolePermissions = await this.rolesPermissionsLogicService.getOneRole({
      name: user.userRole,
      permissions: {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: resourcePermission.resource,
          [`actions.${resourcePermission.scope}`]: true,
        },
      },
    })

    if (!rolePermissions) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Not authorized to access this resource')
    }
    return true
  }
}
```